# Multipage image printing

Tags: html, css, image, printing, multipage

I'm trying to force printing long images on several pages. What would be the best way to achieve this using HTML and / or CSS ?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there's very little cross-browser consistency when it comes to printing, so there's probably no universal solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out that positioning my image with absolute value helps for almost every modern browser.